# Eclipse Tasks vs Java Tasks

Tags: java, eclipse

I've got a strange behaviour in Eclipse IDE.
For some of my projects, `// TODO <comment>` are considered as *Tasks* and for others they are *Java Tasks*

Any idea how this is configured because I've checked my project's configuration and they look the same (basic java projects)?

Comment: These are all in comments in .java files?

Answer (score 0):

You have enabled Task Tags for normal editors in the preferences (which is not activated by default). And those use the same keys like the Java task scanner.

Open *Window->Preferences* and type "todo" in the filter box at the upper left. That will show you at least two different places to configure the task tags (Java and structured editors). You can now disable the one for structured editors, rename or delete keys if you want all to occur under the same label in the problems view.

Comment: Both were disabled. I've tried to activate the java one, same results each time

Comment: Then please also check the project properties of both projects. You can override the workspace settings for "Task Tags" in the project properties.

Comment: My workspace does not have Task Tags enabled nor do any of my Projects have an override.  However, any Java Tasks in one specific project show up as normal Tasks.  Very strange.